# VSTS Agile Process Template - User Story as child of Epic and ignore Feature WIT

Tags: azure-devops, agile, backlog

In Microsoft's VSTS, is there a way to have User Story as a child of Epic in the Agile process template, eg including when performing "mapping", without creating a VSTS custom process template? In the image below in the main content area, hide / remove Feature, and in the "Mapping" panel on the right, have Epics for mapping User Stories.

[image]

I'm asking because in my org's agile practice we have epics and user stories but we don't see the need / benefit to the extra layer of Feature WIT.

OOTB Agile process template has Epic > Feature > User Story and when you view Product Backlog (aka user stories) you can map them to Features and when you view Feature portfolio backlog you can map them to Epics, but you can't (that I know of) turn off the Feature WIT so that User Stories can be mapped directly to Epics in the GUI.

Btw, it isn't possible to rename OOTB WITs otherwise I would simply turn off Epic WIT and rename it to "Epic OOTB", and rename Feature WIT to "Epic My Org".

UPDATE: Per [Add a portfolio backlog level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/vsts/work/customize/add-portfolio-backlogs?view=vsts) it is possible to add a portfolio backlog level with a new WIT:

> You'll first export your process, add or update definition files, and
>   then import that process to either update existing team projects or
>   use it to create a team project.

but I want to remove one. I may try the reverse using this procedure but first I'd like some reassurance that it likely works for removing an OOTB level.

Some of the docs I've consulted include:

- [Agile process work item types and workflow - Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/work-items/guidance/agile-process-workflow?toc=/vsts/work/work-items/toc.json&bc=/vsts/work/breadcrumb/toc.json&view=vsts)
- [Define features and epics - Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/backlogs/define-features-epics?view=vsts)

[image: VSTS Agile process template work item type hierarchy]

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t such feature in VSTS, also you can’t custom too: [Modify the backlog and boards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/settings/work/customize-process?view=vsts#modify-the-backlog-and-boards)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use tools like Jira or Rally to map in your agile practices? It will be immensely beneficial in long run.

Comment: Yea no Jira. Only VSTS.

Answer (score 0):

Agile, by its very definition, means that you should be flexible. As such, ignoring the User Story as a sub-class of feature can be done. However, I think that if the focus of your delivery has a strong user-component to it, then marrying that up in deliverables will give a better indicator to your product owners.
If you're scrumming it, then you'd generally be working on a feature-task loop anyway, so I wouldn't worry, VSTS seems to cope well with both.
VSTS doesn't really concentrate heavy on Workflows OOTB like JIRA pushes (I've seen some crazy JIRA workflows in my time), although it is quite extensible, I believe the VSTS Team have gone Zen Agile in terms of offering a service that helps teams develop code first and foremost, and consigns the machinations of the upper tier management of software delivery and work tracking second.

See the process guidelines for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/boards/work-items/guidance/choose-process?view=vsts